# Swift-3 error: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, swift3

Following code was perfectly worked with old swift. This is an extension of String

```
func stringByConvertingHTML() -> String {
    let newString = replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>")
    if let encodedData = newString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8 as AnyObject
        ]
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil) //Crash here
            return attributedString.string
        } catch {
            return self
        }
    }
    return self
}
```

But in swift 3 it crashes saying

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue
>   unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x6080002565f0'

Anyone please suggest me what need to do?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I ran into the same problem:

```
let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8 as AnyObject
        ]
```

Here the `String.Encoding.utf8` the type check fails. Use `NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. But it'll be `NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`

Comment: Lifesaver!  (PS: Also needed the NSNumber( .. ) to work, could you plz update the answer to include that instead?)

Comment: You should just need `String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`, as Swift will automatically convert `Int`s and `UInt`s into `NSNumber`s when a Swift dictionary is passed to a function expecting an `NSDictionary`. Although that will require having the swift dictionary being a `[String: Any]` array. See also [this](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39) Swift blog entry.

Comment: Sometimes I am getting NSRangeException, any solution to this

Comment: Weird! But it is true, enumerations should be sent as rawValue. I assume it will be fixed in future versions.

Answer (score 48):

In Swift3 no cast to AnyObject is needed anymore and also no NSNumber.

```
let attrs: [String: Any] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
```

Comment: I would say this is the _cleanest_ way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

This post saved my day. After migrating to Swift 3, the little change  `String.Encoding.utf8` to `String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue` fixed the trap reported here.

**Orignal line:**

```
...
    options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8],
...
```

**changed to**

```
options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
```

add the `.rawValue` to the end...

Comment: Would never have guessed from error note that solution was to add .rawValue at the end. Great many thanx!