# Conversion to Swift 3 : SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, unsigned-integer, completionhandler

I wrote a code with Swift 2 and I converted it to Swift 3. Unfortunately, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the incriminated code:

```
func loadImage( url: String?, completionHandler: @escaping( UIImage?, NSError? ) -> Void ) {

    var theSrc: String?

    if let src = url {
        theSrc = src
    } else {
        theSrc = placeHolderImg
    }

    let url = URL( string: theSrc! )!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest( url: url )

    URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: request as URLRequest ) { data, response, error in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage( data:data! )
            completionHandler( image, nil )

        } else {

            completionHandler( nil, error as NSError? )

        }

    }.resume()

}
```

This function is called like this:

```
WordPressWebServices.sharedInstance.loadImage( url: theImgUrl, completionHandler: { ( image, error ) -> Void in

    DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {

        //Some code

    } )

} )
```

Here is what I get from the debug console:

```
2016-10-19 06:40:15.458 tdr-ios-prototype[652:8825] -[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000586f0
2016-10-19 06:40:15.478 tdr-ios-prototype[652:8825] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000586f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dac634b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d52721e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010db35f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da4bc15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da4b798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIFoundation                        0x0000000114e81953 -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1329
    6   UIFoundation                        0x0000000114e82f15 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString] + 22
    7   UIFoundation                        0x0000000114e1945c _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 5779
    8   UIFoundation                        0x0000000114e17d35 -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:] + 115
    9   tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010ceae80d _TTOFE5UIKitCSo18NSAttributedStringcfzT4dataV10Foundation4Data7optionsGVs10DictionarySSP__18documentAttributesGSqGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo12NSDictionary____S0_ + 173
    10  tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010ceae6c4 _TFE5UIKitCSo18NSAttributedStringCfzT4dataV10Foundation4Data7optionsGVs10DictionarySSP__18documentAttributesGSqGVs33AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointerGSqCSo12NSDictionary____S0_ + 100
    11  tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010ceae14f _TFE17tdr_ios_prototypeSSCfT17htmlEncodedStringSS_GSqSS_ + 751
    12  tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010cea4191 _TFFFFC17tdr_ios_prototype11PostManager14getTheLastPostFT_T_U_FTGSqGSaGVs10DictionarySSPs9AnyObject____GSqCSo7NSError__T_U_FTGSqCSo7UIImage_GSqS3___T_U_FT_T_ + 545
    13  tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010cea55c0 _TPA__TFFFFC17tdr_ios_prototype11PostManager14getTheLastPostFT_T_U_FTGSqGSaGVs10DictionarySSPs9AnyObject____GSqCSo7NSError__T_U_FTGSqCSo7UIImage_GSqS3___T_U_FT_T_ + 512
    14  tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010ce7b827 _TTRXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001119e9980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111a130cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001119f38d6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da8a4f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da4ff8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010da4f494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113903a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010e8e8f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    23  tdr-ios-prototype                   0x000000010cea64ff main + 111
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111a5f68d start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I searched on the Internet and found some posts about this kind of error but I couldn't find a solution. Is it a problem of type casting or am I using completion handlers the wrong way?

From what I found, the following line seems to be the problem. Or at least, it is the point where the application crashes.

```
completionHandler( image, nil )
```

The method `loadImage` is part of a process called `LoadTheLastPost`. I am working with the Wordpress REST API V2. Basically an object called `PostManager` is created in `AppDelegate` (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions). This object will call the method `getTheLastPost` included in a class named `WordPressWebServices` which is a singleton. The method `loadImage` is called through `getTheLasPost`. Maybe there is something wrong with that? What do you think?

Maybe I can add that I, after I collected the data, I create a Post object like this:

```
let theLastPost = Post( id: postID!, title: String( htmlEncodedString: title! ), content: String( htmlEncodedString: content! ), imageId: imgID!, imageUrl: theImgUrl, image: theImg )
```

Here is a quick view of my Post class :

```
class Post: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var id: Int
    var title: String?
    var content: String?
    var imageId: Int
    var imageUrl: String?
    var image: UIImage?

    init?( id: Int, title: String?, content: String?, imageId: Int, imageUrl: String?, image: UIImage? ) {

        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.imageId = imageId
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.image = image

        super.init()

        if id < 1 {
            return nil
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Many thanks!

**EDIT**

It seems that I was wrong about the origin of my problem. The problem comes from this line:

```
let theLastPost = Post( id: postID!, title: String( htmlEncodedString: title! ), content: String( htmlEncodedString: content! ), imageId: imgID!, imageUrl: theImgUrl, image: theImg )
```

The `String( htmlEncodedString: title! )` and the `String( htmlEncodedString: content! )` cause the error.

Here is my String extension:

```
extension String {

    init?( htmlEncodedString: String ) {

        let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.data( using: String.Encoding.utf8 )!
        let attributedOptions: [ String: AnyObject ] = [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8 as AnyObject ]

        var attributedString: NSAttributedString?

        do {
            attributedString = try NSAttributedString( data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil )
        } catch {
            print( error )
        }

        self.init( attributedString!.string )

    }

}
```

**SOLUTION**

The problem came from my String extension. Thanks to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644620/1826332, which I saw from the beginning but thought it was something else, I managed to find a solution.

I had to edit the line

```
let attributedOptions: [ String: AnyObject ] = [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8 as AnyObject ]
```

...like this :

```
let attributedOptions: [ String: AnyObject ] = [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as AnyObject ]
```

Comment: where are you calling this method?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your feedback! I updated my question.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer, even though it's to your own question, and mark as correct.