# After migrating to Swift 3, crash on accessing ViewController's view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3

After migrating to Swift 3, the app crashes on

```
-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800064d5f0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800064d5f0'
```

When trying to access `vc.view`. Here is the relevant code snippet. The code is called from a `UIViewController`.

```
guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "some-viewcontroller-id") else { 
    return 
}

if let vc = vc as? SomeViewController {
    let theView: UIView = vc.view
    theView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

If I stop on breakpoint before calling `let theView: UIView = vc.view` and `po vc.view` in the debug window, I get the same error in the debug window.

```
-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntegerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

BUT if I `po vc.view` again I get... **voilà**...

```
Optional<UIView>
```

and the execution can be resumed. I am using Xcode 8.1. Reproduces both on iOS device and simulator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be sure - have you tried the usual - clean, clean build folder, clear derived data, reset simulator (does this happen on simulator or on device), restart Xcode? Which version of Xcode?

Comment: @Losiowaty. I am using Xcode 8.2. Reproduces both on device and Simulator. Yes, I did try all the usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not due to `UIViewController.view`. Your error says that it's `Unrecognized Selector send to instance allocating at some kind of memory index`. If one of ur selector method is private, put @objc in front of it. I can surely say it's not the Nil value error.

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE RESOLVED**

To make a long story short, it is not related to `UIViewController.view` at all! It is related to the `String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue` issue described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644620/396949).

For some reason the crash on simulator didn't give much info except for I already pasted into the question. On device, it produced a much detailed report that helped me find the root cause of this crash.

Answer (score 0):

Make the storyboard-id of the view as "some-viewcontroller-id"
and it would work fine