# How to convert a numeric character reference to a decimal in Swift?

Tags: swift, character, decimal, data-conversion

How to convert this type of string `"&#x38;&#x2e;&#x33;&#x37;"` to its decimal value 8.37?
I'm using Swift 4.

I tried:

```
extension String {

func hexToFloat() -> Float {
    var toInt = Int32(truncatingIfNeeded: strtol(self, nil, 16))
    var float:Float32!
    memcpy(&float, &toInt, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: float))
    return float
}
}

[...]

let myString = "&#x38;&#x2e;&#x33;&#x37;"
let myDecimal = myString.hexToFloat()
print(myDecimal) // prints 0.0
```

[(From here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189338/swift-native-functions-to-have-numbers-as-hex-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no straight forward way (at least to my knowledge). But you can do something like below to get the value. Please note that the code below is in **Swift 3**. You may have to change the syntax.

```
extension String {    
    func hexToFloat() -> Float {
        let data = myString.data(using: .utf8)
        let options: [String: Any] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
        do {
            let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
            return Float(attributedString.string)!
        } catch {
            return 0
        }
    }
}

let myString = "&#x38;&#x2e;&#x33;&#x37;"
let myDecimal = myString.hexToFloat()
print(myDecimal) // prints 8.37
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it works in Swift 3, but I have an error in Swift 4, even after applying the proposed fixes.
The fixed code: `[...] let options: [String: Any] = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType.rawVal‌​ue: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html] [...]`
The error at line 6: "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any]'"

Comment: Try using this `let options: [String: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]`

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing `let options: [String: Any] = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType.rawVal‌​‌​ue: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]` with `let options: [String: Any] = [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]` didn't work. I have this error message in addition to the other one: "Type 'String' has no member 'documentType'"

Comment: Sorry my bad. Remove the line `let options: [String: Any] = .....` completely and then replace the line `let attributedString = try...` with `let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8], documentAttributes: nil)`

Comment: Thank you! It works, after adding `.rawvalue` to `.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8`(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643394/swift-3-error-swiftvalue-unsignedintegervalue-unrecognized-selector).)